# In iCarousel images are overlapping.

Tags: ios, xcode4.3, icarousel

My code is below

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIImageView *imgView = nil;

    if (view == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"no is %i",index);

        view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 255, 255)] autorelease];

        imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ImagesCFArray objectAtIndex:index]] autorelease];

        [view addSubview:imgView];

    }

    else 
    {

    }

    return view;
}
```

ImagesCfArray contains the images to be displayed. 0th index image overlapping with other images when carousel moves or scrolls. Please give me solution for this.

Comment: where you are increasing the index?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your itemWidth implementation? Does it return more than 255?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to tell the subview to clip to its bounds:

`imgView.clipToBounds = YES;`

And also, perhaps use a fill for the image:

`imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`